# Dynamically assign ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to generate a set of check-boxes from an object array. I'm aiming to have the check-boxes dynamically map their ng-model to a property of the new object that will be submitted into the array.

What I had in mind is something like

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <label>{{item.name}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="newObject.{{item.name}}">
</li>
```

This doesn't work as can be seen on this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GreenGeorge/NKjXB/2/

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

This should give you desired results:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="newObject[item.name]">
```

Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ALHQtkjiUDzZVtTfLIOR?p=preview

Comment: hmm actually this literally gave me ' <input ng-model="newObject[item.name]"> ', is it something im missing?

Comment: Hmm, strange, just added a live example (plunker since for some reason jsFiddle is not working on my side today).

Comment: ah yes, i was used to thinking in php and expected the actual markup to change to the name, it worked. thx!

Comment: Great answer! Make sure newObject is an object {} as show in the Plunker.

Comment: It also works great in Angular 2. But is there also a solution for multidimensional objects? In your example, if `item.name` should sometimes point to `newObject['x']` and sometimes to `newObject['x']['y']`.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer in Angular 2/Angular 4 that works with multilevel objects. For example newObject[item.name] would work if item.name is single level such as "someProperty", but what if I need a path "someProperty.someSubproperty" because my object looks like

`"newObject": {"id": 1234
"someProperty": {
 "someSubproperty: "Value to bind to with ngModel"
}
}`

Comment: Dude, I love a short answer thanks! in my case I assigned to my existing Object node $scope.variable.subattr so variable.subattr[item.name]

Answer (score 24):

**EDIT**
As correctly noted in the comments using this with ng-change requires a "dummy" ng-model to be present beforehand. It should however be noted that apparently with 1.3 the required options have been provided by the framework. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/28365515/3497830 below!
**/EDIT**

Just in case you are like me stumbling over a simple case while having a more complex task, this is the solution I came up with for dynamically binding arbitrary expressions to ng-model: http://plnkr.co/edit/ccdJTm0zBnqjntEQfAfx?p=preview

Method: I created a directive dynamicModel that takes a standard angular expression, evaluates it and links the result to the scope via ng-model and $compile.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.testvalue = 'data.foo';
  $scope.eval = $scope.$eval;
});

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.testvalue = 'data.foo';
  $scope.eval = $scope.$eval;
});

app.directive('dynamicModel', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        'link': function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamicModel, function(dynamicModel) {
                if (attrs.ngModel == dynamicModel || !dynamicModel) return;

                element.attr('ng-model', dynamicModel);
                if (dynamicModel == '') {
                    element.removeAttr('ng-model');
                }

                // Unbind all previous event handlers, this is 
                // necessary to remove previously linked models.
                element.unbind();
                $compile(element)(scope);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Usage is simply dynamic-model="angularExpression" where angularExpression results in a string that is used as the expression for ng-model.

I hope this saves someone the headache of having to come up with this solution.

Regards,
Justus

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I almost despaired before finding this post.

Comment: Can you be more specific Brian? What did you try and what happened?

Comment: This is a compete gem of a solution. You've gotten me out of a very sticky issue - thanks!

Comment: ng-change does not work with this. If you look in the angular source, the ngChange directive has ngModel as a required directive. A quick search shows only ngChange and ngList have this issue. All other directives seem to have ngModel as an optional controller. I worked around this problem by adding an ng-model="dummyValue" to any element using the dynamic-model directive. Since a change to dynamic-model calls $compile, ngChange and any other directives using the ng-model value are updated correctly.

Comment: This is a more robust solution, when you don't need to watch the dynamic-model value changing - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32096328/887092

Answer (score 6):

With Angular 1.3, you can use `ng-model-options` directive to dynamically assign the model, or bind to an expression.

Here is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/65EBiySUc1iWCWG6Ov98?p=preview

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name"><br>
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" 
ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }">
```

More info on `ngModelOptions` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but nothing about your plunk appears to include dynamic model assignment. And nothing about ngModelOptions would obviously support that. Could you perhaps clarify? Because it would be super-useful if it did, in fact, work that way...

Comment: @XMLilley "getterSetter: boolean value which determines whether or not to treat functions bound to ngModel as getters/setters."

Comment: Thanks Rob for bringing this to my attention, I have updated my answer and linked to yours.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach to support deeper expression, e.g. 'model.level1.level2.value'

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="Utility.safePath(model, item.modelPath).value">
```

where item.modelPath = 'level1.level2' and
Utility(model, 'level1.level2') is the utility function that returns model.level1.level2

Comment: Can you expand on how this works? What does Utility.safePath return such that you can then use .value?

Comment: Utility.safePath returns the value of the nested variable specified by the path string. e.g. level1.level2 refers to model.level1.level2.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form name="priceForm" ng-submit="submitPriceForm()">
            <div ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(9) track by $index">
                <label>
                    Person {{$index+1}} <span class="warning-text">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="person{{$index+1}}" ng-model="price['person'+($index+1)]" />

            </div>
            <button>Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.price = [];
            $scope.submitPriceForm = function () {
                //objects be like $scope.price=[{person1:value},{person2:value}....]
                console.log($scope.price);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```