# Variable as a model in scope

Tags: angularjs, view, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I use a variable as model description in a scope?

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="foo in foos">
        <input ng-model="{{model.{{foo.desc}}.newModel}}"></input>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The model part `{{model.{{foo.desc}}.newModel}}` obviously doesn't work. What's the correct way of doing this?

Edit: This should work, but doesn't:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="lang in languages">
        <input ng-model="model.[lang.desc].someInput"></input>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you mean this `model[foo.desc].newModel`. Don't use interpolation symbol `{{}}` in ng-model.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183614/in-angularjs-how-do-i-dynamically-assign-ng-model

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate of said question. Thanks!