# ng-model with dynamic form inputs

Tags: angularjs, forms

I'm having trouble dynamically capturing form inputs in angular. I have a form that takes several inputs for a resource. Each resource has many sections, and each section has many links. I've been able to get the functionality to work for a user to dynamically add/remove sections and links, but when it comes to actually capturing that with ng-model I can't seem to get it.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183614/dynamically-assign-ng-model) stackoverflow post, I thought I could do something like the first answer, `ng-model="newResourceForm.sections[section.title]"`, but that doesn't seem to be working for me (it says that it is undefined)

Here is a link to a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2hCUUBbZoNVyv6cM61Ns?p=preview) that I made for it:

Comment: Hey did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem in your code is that you are binding your variables to

```
newResourceForm.sections
```

but you are creating new sections inside an array named `sections` without a title property.

Using `ng-model="newResourceForm.sections[section.title]"` works but `section.title` is undefined. The result is your `newResourceForm.sections` object contains just one section named `undefined` no matter how many objects you have in your `sections` array.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're adding/editing sections is a little off.  It's hard to say without looking at your controller code, but I think this is part of the issue:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in sections" class="form-group mt">
```

and it should look more like

```
<div ng-repeat="section in resource.sections" class="form-group mt">
```

I made a really minimal working version of what I think you were going for, feel free to try it out! (you just have to change the location of angular.min.js)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="static/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('resourseCtrl', resourseCtrl);

      function resourseCtrl() {
        this.resource = {'sections': []};
        console.log('controller started');
        this.addSection = function() {
          this.resource.sections.push({});
        };
        this.removeSection = function() {
          this.resource.sections.splice(this.resource.sections.length - 1, 1);
        };
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="resourseCtrl as resourseCtrl">
      <button ng-click="resourseCtrl.addSection()">add section</button>
      <button ng-click="resourseCtrl.removeSection()">remove section</button>
      <div ng-repeat="section in resourseCtrl.resource.sections">
        <p>name:<input text ng-model="section.name"></input></p>
        <p>title:<input text ng-model="section.title"></input></p>
        <p>description:<input text ng-model="section.description"></input></p>
      </div>
      {{ resourseCtrl.resource }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```