# Append index to object reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I change this:

```
ng-messages="createCourseForm.quizItemMultipleChoiceAnswer+$index.$error"
```

into:

```
ng-messages="createCourseForm.quizItemMultipleChoiceAnswer0.$error"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically assign ng-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183614/dynamically-assign-ng-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access a specifically named property from your form.  If you need the property name to be variable, you can use javascript's [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for accessing properties.  Then you can pass in any string and access the property.

```
ng-messages="createCourseForm['quizItemMultipleChoiceAnswer' + $index].$error"
```