# Dynamically assigning ng-model inside a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Similar to [Dynamically assign ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183614/dynamically-assign-ng-model) except the solutions provided assign it to the same element.  What I would want to do is assign it to elements inside the element.

For example given a form

```
<form name="myForm" my-directive controller="MyController as me">
  <input name="email">
  <input name="password">
  <button type="submit" ng-click="me.submit()">
</form>
```

I would like it to transform to

```
<form name="myForm" my-directive controller="MyController as me">
  <input name="email" ng-model="email">
  <input name="password" ng-model="password">
  <button type="submit" ng-click="me.submit()">
</form>
```

I was thinking it was the compile with "pre" then do a $compile but I seem to get the side effect of the ng-click being assigned twice.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so ? Any specific benefit ?

Comment: to avoid having to repeat yourself.  see how name and ng-model are the same?

Comment: Anyway I think I got most of the solution down now, trying to figure out why my "sub-directive" isn't working without doing some ridiculous DOM hacks.

Comment: You can use `terminal: true` to stop compilation, then trigger it manually with `$compile`

Comment: Thanks @AndrésEsguerra I got that far. Perhaps you can write it up into a formal answer.  I am still trying to make sure sub-directives work myself.

Comment: This is the context I am using it from https://plnkr.co/edit/mwAP9temZaz8RaB0GjHv?p=preview and

https://github.com/trajano/angular-bootstrap-validator