# prevent reflecting ng-model value across all select tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new to AngularJS. I am working on a project wherein I need to append certain html select tags based on a button click. Each select tag is bound to a ng-model attribute (which is hardcoded). Now the problem I am facing is, once I append more than 2 such html templates and make changes in a select tag then value selected is reflected across all the tags bound to the corresponding ng-model attribute (which is pretty obvious). I would like to know if there is a way around it without naming each ng-model differently.

JS code:

```
EsConnector.directive("placeholderid", function($compile, $rootScope, queryService, chartOptions){

 return {
 restrict : 'A',
 scope : true,


 link : function($scope, element, attrs){

$scope.current_mount1 = "iscsi";
$scope.current_dedupe1 = "on";
$scope.y_axis_param1 = "Total iops";
var totalIops =[];
var totalBandwidth =[];

    element.bind("click", function(){




        $scope.count++;
        $scope.placeholdervalue = "placeholder12"+$scope.count;




        var compiledHTML = $compile('<span class="static" id='+$scope.placeholdervalue+'>choose mount type<select ng-bind="current_mount1" ng-options="o as o for o in mount_type"></select>choose dedupe<select ng-model="current_dedupe1" ng-options="o as o for o in dedupe"></select>choose y axis param<select ng-model="y_axis_param1" ng-options="o as o for o in y_axis_param_options"></select></span><div id='+$scope.count+' style=width:1400px;height:300px></div>')($scope);


        $("#space-for-buttons").append(compiledHTML);

        $scope.$apply();




    $(".static").children().each(function() {


            $(this).on("change", function(){
            var id = $(this).closest("span").attr("id");

            var chartId = id.slice(-1);


            queryService.testing($scope.current_mount1, $scope.current_dedupe1, function(response){
            var watever = response.hits.hits;

            dataToBePlot = chartOptions.calcParams(watever, totalIops, totalBandwidth, $scope.y_axis_param1);

            chartOptions.creatingGraph(dataToBePlot, $scope.y_axis_param1, chartId);


        });




            });

    });

    });
}
 }

   });
```

Code explanation:
This is just the directive which I am posting.I am appending my compiledHTML and doing $scope.apply to set the select tags to their default values. Whenever any of the select tags are changed I am doing a set of operations (function calls to services) on the values selected.

As you can see the ng-model attribute being attached is the same. So when one select tag is changed the value is reflected on all the appended HTML even though the data displayed does not match to it.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183614/dynamically-assign-ng-model

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [PLunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0KDTIcfUjVcGfa9oKLCb?p=preview) is useful for you. You need to have one way binding over such attributes

```
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p> 
<input ng-model="name"/>
<br>Single way binding: {{::name}}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question

Comment: Hi Shashank thanks for your reply. Can you have a look at my above comments to get a better idea of my requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to understand your whole requirement from your description and your code, correct me if I'm wrong: you are trying to dynamically add a dropdown on a button click and then trying to keep track on each of them.

If you are giving the same `ng-model` for each generated items, then they are bound to the same object, and their behavior is synchronized, that is how angular works.

What you can do is, change your structure to an array, and then assigning `ng-model` to the elements, so you can conveniently keep track on each of them. I understand you came from `jquery` base on your code, so let me show you the `angular` way of doing things.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope) {
  $scope.itemArray = [
    { id: 1, selected: "op1" },
    { id: 2, selected: "op2" }
  ];
  
  $scope.optionList = [
    { name: "Option 1", value: "op1" },
    { name: "Option 2", value: "op2" },
    { name: "Option 3", value: "op3" }
  ]
  
  $scope.addItem = function() {
    var newItem = { id: $scope.itemArray.length + 1, selected: "" };
    $scope.itemArray.push(newItem);
  }
  
  $scope.changeItem = function(item) {
    alert("changed item " + item.id + " to " + item.selected);
  }
}
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <button type='button' ng-click='addItem()'>Add</button>
  <select ng-repeat='item in itemArray' 
          ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in optionList'
          ng-model='item.selected'
          ng-change='changeItem(item)'></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I can try this out. I will list my requirements as clearly as possible.

Comment: First: On a button click I need to add an html template which has multiple drop downs. I should be able to add as many such html templates I want. Second: On selecting certain value of a drop down of a particular html template, I need to get values of all the corresponding drop downs in that particular html template so that I can fire a query to the backend >> fetch data >> plot chart in that particular html template's placeholder id. Hope this makes things a bit more clearer and apologies for code structure.

Comment: The above code should be fine if I needed to add a single drop down per html template but I need to added multiple drop downs (could range from 4-5) per html template

Comment: @nishantsalvi By html templates do you mean you need different layout designs for them or just different options in the select(s)?

Comment: It will also help greatly if you can provide some real world example using  train/fruit/car etc. It's a bit hard to understand your purpose from the general description