# AngularJS - Dynamic Checkboxes to hide/show Divs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I'm new to front-end web development. I am creating checkboxes dynamically using AngularJS.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in Brands" style="margin-left: 20px">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="newObject[x.product_brand]">
   <label> {{ x.product_brand }} </label>
</div>
```

Following the methods given on the links below, I want to hide/show divs using
using the dynamically created checkboxes.

1. [Dynamic ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183614/dynamically-assign-ng-model)
2. [ng-show](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-show.asp)

Here's the code-

```
<div class="item panel panel-default" ng-repeat="x in Brands" ng-show="newObject[x.product_brand]">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        {{x.product_brand}}
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller-**

```
app.controller('BrandController', function($scope, $http) {
    getProductsInfo();

    function getProductsInfo() {
        $http.get("sql.php").success(function(data) {
            $scope.Brands = data;
        });
    };
});
```

But it is not working. Checking/Unchecking the checkboxes does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this [runnable fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8x60xrry/). This kind of handle is easy to manage with AngularJS. Welcome =) !!! Please note: The `$timeout` is to simulate your async `$http` request - its not a part of the solution.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in Brands" style="margin-left: 20px">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.active">
     <label> {{ x.product_brand }} </label>
  </div>
  <div class="item panel panel-default" ng-repeat="x in Brands" ng-show="x.active">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        {{x.product_brand}}
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS demo application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {

   $scope.Brands = [];

   init();

   function init () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.Brands = [{
                product_brand: 'brand 1'
            },{
                product_brand: 'brand 2'
            },{
                product_brand: 'brand 3'
            },{
                product_brand: 'brand 4'
            }];
        });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is not working because you never defined *newObject* on the *$scope*. So actually you are trying to access `undefined[x.product_brand]`.

Something like `$scope.newObject = {};` in your Controller should do the trick.

Comment: @Abhishek Here is a Fiddle. Works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/mx56nsL3/1/

Comment: Thanks! It was my mistake, I declared the newObject in another controller.