# How to generates dynamically ng-model="my_{{$index}}" with ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to ask you if you can give me a hand on this.

I have created a jsfiddle with my problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jLRJ/). I need to generate dynamically some inputs with ng-model in a ng-repeater using the way ng-model="my_{{$index}}".

In jsfiddle you can see that everything it's working fine until I try to generate it dynamically.

The html would be:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select ng-model="selectedQuery" 
        ng-options="q.name for q in queryList" >
        <option title="---Select Query---" value="">---Select Query---</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="param in parameters">
    <td>{{param}}:</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="field_X" />field_{{$index}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
<div>
```

And the javascript...

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.queryList = [
    { name: 'Check Users', fields: [ "Name", "Id"] },
    { name: 'Audit Report', fields: [] },
    { name: 'Bounce Back Report', fields: [ "Date"] } 
  ];

$scope.$watch('selectedQuery', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.parameters = $scope.selectedQuery.fields;
  });
}
```

Can you give me any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set a dynamic model name in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553617/how-can-i-set-a-dynamic-model-name-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Does it solve your problem?

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.queryList = [
        { name: 'Check Users', fields: [ "Name", "Id"] },
        { name: 'Audit Report', fields: [] },
        { name: 'Bounce Back Report', fields: [ "Date"] } 
      ];
    $scope.models = {};
    $scope.$watch('selectedQuery', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if ($scope.selectedQuery) {
            $scope.parameters = $scope.selectedQuery.fields;
        }
    });
}
```

And in your controller:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="param in parameters">
    <td>{{param}}:</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="models[param] " />field_{{$index}}</td>
  </tr>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jLRJ/2/)

Answer (score 24):

What you could do is to create an object on a scope (say, `values`) and bind to the properties of this object like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="values['field_' + $index]" />
```

Here is a jsFiddle illustrating the complete solution: http://jsfiddle.net/KjsWL/

Comment: You are tracking through the $index which is/will be unique for each row. If I need to track also on the colum basis, what would you suggest? I mean values[$index][columnIndex] ...How to give this column index?

Answer (score 4):

I did elaborate my answer from pkozlowski's and try to generate a dynamic form, with dynamic ng-model:

```
<form ng-submit="testDynamic(human)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="human.adult[($index+1)].name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="human.adult[($index+1)].sex">
    <input type="text" ng-model="human.adult[($index+1)].age">
</form>
```

But first, we need to define the 'human' scope inside our controller

```
$scope.human= {};
```

And then, on submission we will have the data like this (depending on how much field is generated):

```
var name = human.adult[i].name;
var sex = human.adult[i].sex;
var age = human.adult[i].age;
```

It's pretty straightforward and I hope my answer helps.

Comment: very straight forward and simple!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason to generate those field names?  Can you treat each field as an object with name and value instead of a string name? [(FIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/WZLA7/)

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.queryList = [
         { name: 'Check Users', fields: [ { name: "Name" },  { name: "Id" } ] },
         { name: 'Audit Report', fields: [] },
         { name: 'Bounce Back Report', fields: [ { name: "Date" } ] } 
      ];
}
```

And just repeat off of `selectedQuery.fields`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="field in selectedQuery.fields">
    <td>{{field.name}}:</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="field.value" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I need that in order to generate queries to mongodb, and this queries are previously stored in a collection. The idea of this is fetch this queries and execute each query to mongo.

Comment: By the way, both solution above have helped me to solve the trouble. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Beterraba's answer was very helpful for me.  However, when I had to migrate the solution to Typescript it wouldn't behave for me.  Here is what I did instead.  I expanded the individual parameters (fields on the queryList in your example) into full objects that included a "value" field.  I then bound to the "value" field and it worked great!

Originally you had:

```
[
  { name: 'Check Users', fields: [ "Name", "Id"] },
    ...
  }
]
```

I changed it to something like this:

```
[
  { name: 'Check Users', fields: [
                                    {Text:"Name",Value:""},
                                    {Text:"Id",Value:0}],
                                    ...
                                   ]
  }
]
```

...and bound to the 'Value' sub-field.

Here is my Typescript if you care.

In the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="param in ctrl.sprocparams" >
    <sproc-param param="param" />
</div>
```

In the sproc-param directive that uses Angular Material. See where I bind the ng-model to param.Value:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>{{param.Name}}</label>
                    <input  name="{{param.Name}}" ng-model=param.Value></input>
                </md-input-container>`,
    scope: {
            param: "="
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to generate dynamically some inputs with ng-model in a ng-repeater using the way `ng-model="my_{{$index}}"`.

One can use the `this` identifier with a bracket notation [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
  <tr ng-repeat="param in parameters">
    <td>{{param}}:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="this['my_'+$index]" />
      my_{{$index}}
    </td>
  </tr>
```

It is possible to access the $scope object using the identifier `this`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression Context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context)