# How to get the content out of an editable div in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to get the content out of an editable div. But i am stuck at implementing the angular template for it.

I am not sure how to map model data from html template to angular controller.

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">                 
    <div class="todo.id" ng-model={{ ? }} contenteditable="true">
        <pre>{{ todo.text }}</pre>                          
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"
        ng-click="editTodo(todo.id)">Edit</button>
</div>
```

I want to pass whatever text i have under

```
<div class="todo.id"></div>
```

Since my div is under ng-repeat, i cannot set ng-model to one scope variable.

What should i have within "ng-model={{ ? }}". Or is there a workaround for such a scenario.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: i dont understand ur scenario...

Comment: I have added more desc. Hope its clear now. I dont know what to write within 'ng-model' so that i can pass the value within a particular div, to angular controller.

Comment: still its unclear.  u dont tell us what you exactly want?  u want new scope?  or u want to show ng repeat  values in div tag.....?

Comment: Try `ng-model="model[$index]"`

Comment: u want to bind todo-text vale to  new model???

Comment: I think, he use `ngModel` attr for own purpose in `contenteditable` directive. Better to use any attribute w/o `ng-` prefix in this case.

Comment: And yes, `todo.text` already mapped to your controller as `$scope.todos[$index]`

Comment: @micronyks i want to read the value of 'div class="todo.id"', when i click the button for any of the todo item.

Comment: @vp_arth Thanks for that. I got a usage of your suggestion on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573001/how-to-generates-dynamically-ng-model-my-index-with-ng-repeat-in-angularj

Comment: @vp_arth on your third comment i have a question. Does that mean, i whatever change i do inside the contenteditable div, i can read the same under my controller through $scope.todos[$index]?

Comment: if your directive changes your `todo.text` only. I can't to know, how your `contenteditable` works :)

Comment: May be you should write `ng-model="todo.text"` for this. Also you should remove any content like `<pre>...` inside.

Comment: its simple... use ng-click=editToDo( $index, todo)... it will return whole object with its index which u can manipulate according to ur needs....todo. id is the one assigned to ur individual div class.  manipulate it accordingly.

Comment: that picks up the right element, but not picking the updated 'todo' value, after the div content is edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a div content editable in angular, you need to create a contenteditable directive.

There is an example for this in the angular documentation here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example

and a great blog entry from Gabo Esquivel on the topic here:
http://gaboesquivel.com/blog/2014/in-place-editing-with-contenteditable-and-angularjs/

As you can see in Gabriel's example, the code for such a directive would be like this (I've added some comments to better understand whats going on):

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      //read the text typed in the div (syncing model with the view)
      function read() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
      }

      //render the data now in your model into your view
      //$render is invoked when the modelvalue differs from the viewvalue
      //see documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
      };

      //do this whenever someone starts typing
      element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
        scope.$apply(read);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that. I am too new too understand all that. I will learn more and try that out :)

Comment: I highly recommend that you learn directives, services, and factories.  They are the real powerhouses behind Angular.  Dan Wahlin has great video tutorials on how to create directives.  I highly recommend looking into them.

Comment: @user3527354 I got this working now. I guess that implementing a directive for a div type is mandatory to be editable(unlike input tag). Thanks alot.