# Angular dynamic ng-model name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-forms

```
<div class="pw-form-control-text" id="disclosureQuestionsPrepopulate" name="disclosureQuestionsPrepopulate"  ng-repeat="type in (prepopulatingFieldData|prepopulateValue:'c2a39346-9e95-e411-bd87-00155d005107')" >

<div >
<input name="{{type.Id}}" ng-model="formData.disclosureQuestionsPrepopulate"($index + 1) ng-click="option.selected = true" type="radio" value=true >Yes</input>

</input>
```

here what I want to do is my ng-model name should be like this

> formData.disclosureQuestionsPrepopulate1",
>   formData.disclosureQuestionsPrepopulate2

like that but it doesnt work.
Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generates dynamically ng-model="my\_{{$index}}" with ng-repeat in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573001/how-to-generates-dynamically-ng-model-my-index-with-ng-repeat-in-angularj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should use `[]` to assign create a array for `ng-model` variable & also Value attribute should be `ng-value` to ensure binding with check box

**HTML**

```
<input ng-attr-name="{{type.Id}}" 
ng-model="formData['disclosureQuestionsPrepopulate'+($index + 1)]" 
ng-click="option.selected = true" type="radio" ng-value="true"/>Yes
```