# Referencing a dynamically created ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which allows users to upload a json that fills this blank form with select/textbox inputs. Because these inputs are dynamically generated (as it's based on the json they upload), I need to be able to reference the answers they input (the ng-model).

So say the json looks like:
`var jsonObj=[
    {"type": "select", "label": "Name", "values": ["a", "b", "c"], "default": "a"},
    {"type": "select", "label": "Age", "values": [1, 2, 3]}
]`

and I dynamically insert those inputs within a for loop via:

```
var newInputCol='<' + jsonObj[i].type + ' ng-model="' + jsonObj[j].label + '" class="form-control" ></' + jsonObj[j].type + '>';
var newInputRowElement = angular.element(newInputRow);
element.append(newInputRowElement);
$compile(newInputRowElement)($scope);
```

Also, I'm not using ng-repeat in the html as I'm trying to lay it out so there's a new row per 3 inputs in the json. But in order to do so, would I need to use ng-repeat? All the answers I've seen use ng-repeat and a empty object for referencing (like: [How to generates dynamically ng-model="my_{{$index}}" with ng-repeat in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573001/how-to-generates-dynamically-ng-model-my-index-with-ng-repeat-in-angularj))

What would I need to do to console.log all the ng-models after the user has filled out their self generated form after a button click (which can be done by placing a function in a button onclick or ng-click)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, a simple $scope[$scope.jsonObj[i].label] can reference it. Is there another way or should I stick with this?