# Dynamic ng-model name in AngularJS form

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have an AngularJS form where I'm using ng-repeat to build the fields of the form dynamically based on another selection. I'm trying to generate the model name dynamically and am running into problems.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="parameter in apiParameters">
  <label for="{{parameter.paramName}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{parameter.paramTitle}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{parameter.paramName}}" id="{{parameter.paramName}}" ng-model="formData.parameters.{{parameter.paramName}}" placeholder="{{parameter.paramTitle}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need is it to eval to something like ng-model="formData.parameters.fooId" or ng-model="formData.parameters.barId"

The above results in an error:
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 21 of the expression [formData.parameters.{{parameter.paramName}}] starting at [{{parameter.paramName}}].

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.formData = {
  settings:
  {
    apiEndpoint: '',
    method: 'get'
  },
  parameters: {}
};
```

I've also tried ng-model="formData.parameters.[parameter.paramName]" (based on this question [How can I set a dynamic model name in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553617/how-can-i-set-a-dynamic-model-name-in-angularjs)), but that doesn't eval and fails to set the ng-model value. I'm not sure if what I'm trying to accomplish is even possible. I'm assuming I need to go through the controller to achieve what I want, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick note: in your ng-repeat you reference apiParameters but only have parameters defined in your scope's formData. Also, a fiddle or plnkr would be helpful to work off of.

Comment: I think you should consider writing a directive that has a isolated scope that allows you to pass in the object you'd like to modify.  Also agree with Brocco a pnlkr is preferable to work through issues since ultimately can save to GitHub and use in the future for reference.

Comment: Duly noted. I'll take the time to add a fiddle in the future and I'll keep the directive approach in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just need to use hash key as model:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="parameter in apiParameters">
  <label for="{{parameter.paramName}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{parameter.paramTitle}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{parameter.paramName}}" id="{{parameter.paramName}}" ng-model="formData.parameters[parameter.paramName]" placeholder="{{parameter.paramTitle}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

There is many other approaches, but this one are simpler than others.

Comment: Ugh, I had the period in there by mistake. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: You welcome. It's common approach for dynamic models in angular.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this solution but it has a problem for my self. The problem is that the parameter "formData" is assigned to each iteration individually. In the other words if you insert a ***pre*** tag in every iteration you will see the value of each iteration individually and you cannot get all the formData in your controller after submitting the form.

For this I have found a very simple solution and it is the ng-init !!!!

Simply add this code to your form and before your repetitive tag. For the example of this question we will have:

```
<form ng-init="formData = []">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="parameter in apiParameters">
        <label for="{{parameter.paramName}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{parameter.paramTitle}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{parameter.paramName}}" id="{{parameter.paramName}}" ng-model="formData.parameters[parameter.paramName]" placeholder="{{parameter.paramTitle}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```