# concatenate string with scope variable inside ng-model

Tags: angularjs, concatenation, angular-ngmodel

How to concatenate string with scope variable and assign it to ng-model

is there a way ti express this

```
ng-model="'is'+location.placeName+'Checked'"
```

Comment: You can write javascript expression inside ng-model directive. Your code should work, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553617/how-can-i-set-a-dynamic-model-name-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-bind-model instead of ng-model in this case

```
ng-bind-model="is{{location.placeName}}Checked"
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer randomly in this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/PSvwCE/) by [ozkary](https://plnkr.co/users/ozkary) using `ng-init`

HTML View

```
<input ng-model="isPlaceChecked" ng-init="isPlaceChecked = checkIfPlaceChecked(location.placeName)"
```

JS Controller

```
    $scope.checkIfPlaceChecked = function (placeName) {
        return "is" + placeName + "Checked";
    }
```