# dynamic ng-model in ng-repeat and get in controller angular js

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I want dynamic ng-model in ng-repeat and want to get value of these ng-models in controller. I searched it on google and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553617/how-can-i-set-a-dynamic-model-name-in-angularjs) solution of stackoverflow. But it's giving me undefined in my case.I don't know why so.

My HTML code is

```
 <div class="item" ng-repeat="question in quiz_questions">
            <p ng-bind-html="question.question"></p>
        <div class="dh_yabox">
            <div class="placeholder">Your Answer:</div>
            <input ng-model="answers[question.question]" class="ansf" type="text" />
        </div>
</div>    



<div ng-click="nextQuestion()" class="pay_btn btn_defa"><a class="next">Next Question</a></div>
```

Controller code is

```
$scope.nextQuestion = function(){
        console.log($scope.answers);
        angular.element('.slick-next').triggerHandler('click');
    }
```

and in quiz_questions following is the data

```
       [{"qid":"3","question":"<p>First Quiz Q2</p>\r\n\r\n<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"http://localhost/project/backend/uploads/qt-01.png\" style=\"width: 520px; height: 390px;\" /></p>\r\n","quiz_id":"6","answer":"test,question","time":"2016-09-22 12:43:28","quiz_name":"free quiz","id":"6"},{"qid":"1","question":"First Quiz Q1","quiz_id":"6","answer":"test,test1,test2","time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","quiz_name":"free quiz","id":"6"}]
```

Can any body please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Post a complete example in a plunkr that reproduces the error. The posted code doesn't even have any ng-repeat, and we have no idea what the error is, and when it happens.

Comment: What happens in function, called by `angular.element('.slick-next').triggerHandler('click');` ?

Comment: this statement is just to show new slide. just before this line of code I am consoling answers which is coming undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few problems,

- Initialized your `ng-model` as `$scope.answers = {};`
- Where is `.slick-next` that you're triggering from your function ?
- Check / Debug in your `console` if it gives any errors.
- Bind HTML using `$sce.trustAsHtml();`

See the working example

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.answers = {};
  $scope.quiz_questions = [{"qid":"3","question":"<b>First Quiz Q2<b/>","quiz_id":"6","answer":"test,question","time":"2016-09-22 12:43:28","quiz_name":"free quiz","id":"6"},{"qid":"1","question":"<b>First Quiz Q1</b>","quiz_id":"6","answer":"test,test1,test2","time":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","quiz_name":"free quiz","id":"6"}];
  
  $scope.nextQuestion = function(){
        console.log($scope.answers);
        //angular.element('.slick-next').triggerHandler('click');
    }
  
  $scope.get_pre = function(x) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(x);
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div  ng-controller="GreetingController">
<div class="item" ng-repeat="question in quiz_questions">
                 <p ng-bind-html="get_pre(question.question)"></p>
        <div class="dh_yabox">
            <div class="placeholder">Your Answer:</div>
            <input ng-model="answers[question.question]" class="ansf" type="text" />
        </div>
</div>    


<div ng-click="nextQuestion()" class="pay_btn btn_defa"><a class="next">Next Question</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: yeah it worked just after adding $scope.answers = {}; but can you explain why do I need to initialize?

Comment: AngularJS is still JavaScript. So the variable needs to declare before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it's `dot` problem. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607794/5986834)

Try to use in your controller

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.answers = {};
```

and

```
<div class="dh_yabox">
    <div class="placeholder">Your Answer:</div>
    <input ng-model="model.answers[question.id]" class="ansf" type="text" />
</div>
```

because ng-repeat create own scope and it brokes binding

Comment: no its not working with model.

Comment: yeap, sorry. Not usefull answer

Answer (score 0):

It is because $scope.answers is not initialized in your controller. Initialize it as an empty object.

```
$scope.answers = {};
```

Comment: no its not working though its giving blank object in console.